# Why there's no default constructor available for struct?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have a structure:

```
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

and am trying to initialize it:

```
ListNode* res = new ListNode();
ListNode* start = res;
```

but am getting:

```
error C2512: 'ListNode' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

Why?

Comment: Regarding the many downvotes here. Downvoters should find an appropriate duplicate or shut up please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but am getting:
>
> ```
> error C2512: 'ListNode' : no appropriate default constructor available
> ```
>
> Why?

Sure you get that error, because you don't have a default constructor declared for `ListNode`. The error message is pretty clear regarding that point.

As soon you declare a  custom constructor `ListNode(int x);` the compiler doesn't anymore generate the default constructor for you.

---

To fix that, either declare a default constructor<sup>1</sup>

```
 ListNode() : val(), next(NULL) {}
```

or call the declared one

```
 ListNode* res = new ListNode(42);
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> `struct` behaves by no means differently from `class` regarding this (in case this should have been causing your confusion).

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
ListNode* res = new ListNode();
```

there is called the default constructor.

However according to the structure definition

```
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

the structure has a parametrized constructor.

In fact there is no need to declare a constructor for this structure.

It is better to declare it as an aggregate

```
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
};
```

Initailly the list should be a `nullptr` pointer. For example

```
ListNode *start = nullptr;
```

If you want that initially the list contained a node then you could write for example

```
ListNode *start = new ListNode { 10, nullptr };
```

Answer (score -1):

The compiler wouldn't generate a default for you because you've defined a constructor. Just add a default constructor to it *or add a default to your parameter* (Not same as a default constructor in the strict sense), like this

```
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x = 0) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

Also, use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but adding a default parameter value doesn't solve all cases maybe.